# How can I embed a `QTabWidget` inside a `QVBoxLayout`?

Tags: pyside6, qt6

This is what I am getting when embedding a `QTabWidget` inside a `QVBoxLayout`:

[image]

And this is the code - what am I doing wrong?

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QTabWidget,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.label = QLabel("Label")

        self.tab_widget = QTabWidget()
        self.tab_widget.addTab(self.label, "Tab")

        # # This works:
        # self.setCentralWidget(self.tab_widget)
        # # But we may want to add something beneath the tabs.

        # So, put the tabs into a vertical layout:
        self.v_box_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.v_box_layout.addChildWidget(self.tab_widget)
        # (maybe some more ...)

        # # This doesn't show anything
        # self.setLayout(self.v_box_layout)

        # This doesn't, either:
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.v_box_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.show()

application = QApplication()
window = Window()
application.exec()
```

Comment: Change `addChildWidget` to `addWidget`

Comment: Typo: use `self.v_box_layout.addWidget(self.tab_widget)`.

Comment: Thanks, both! This is it, what a stupid mistake...